# Determine if `.` and `..` are "special names" in a Java file system

Tags: java, filesystems, filenames

I've been accustomed to thinking that `.` and `..` are *always* filenames with special meanings. But some Java 11 APIs such as [`Path.normalize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize()) indicate that this is true only on some file system implementations:

> In many file systems, the "." and ".." are special names used to indicate the current directory and parent directory.

If `.` and `..` are "special names" only on some file systems, how can I query the file system to know if those names are special for that [`FileSystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) implementation?

Comment: If you are running on a mainframe or on vms you probably know it. You might have to do something hokey with `System.getProperty("os.name")` - this is a highly unusual "special case" (at least I think it is).

Comment: That's a huge assumption—that I would just automatically know that I was running on a mainframe, or that I would even know to check or even care whether I was running on a mainframe. The whole point of the new Java [`FileSystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize()) and related classes was to remove the need to have these special OS checks. That's why e.g. we should be using `Path.resolve()` rather than constructing paths manually using some determined separator, etc.

Comment: Although I agree with you that `.` and `..` not being "special names" would probably be an unusual case on modern systems. Still, if the API allows for them not being special names, I need to know how to tell if they are or not.

Comment: Java runs on unusual systems, [some](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076641/an-introduction-to-the-java-ring.html) don't even have file systems. Note this is just a comment, I don't have an ***answer*** for you.

Comment: Just a side note: I love that you pulled out a reference to a product from 1998. :D Ah, the dreams we had for Java back then.

Comment: *I love that you pulled out a reference to a product from 1998. :D Ah, the dreams we had for Java back then.* [Still **available**](https://www.ibutton.cc/).

Answer (score 2):

There is no specification that requires a `FileSystem` implementation to give you this information.

So even if *some* `FileSystem` would give you this information you cannot be sure if you are not dealing with a file system that does not give you this information.

If you really care about this information and need it for your code to work correctly your only option is something along the line

```
Map<String, Object> env = new HashMap<>();
FileSystem f = FileSystems.newFileSystem(new URI("rw:///"), env);

boolean equalsDoesntNormalize = !f.getPath("a/./b").equals(f.getPath("a/b"));
boolean equalAfterNormalize = f.getPath("a/./b").normalize().equals(f.getPath("a/b"));
boolean dotIsSpecial = equalAfterNormalize && !equalsDoesntNormalize;
```

But, to be honest: I don't think that you need this information...